# GRUB not working MBR broken

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-xp

I have a laptop with Windows XP Professional SP3 on it, later on i dual-booted the machine with ubuntu 13.04. I used a program call AOMEI partition assistant for the partitioning. Windows 8.1 preview came out and i thought to give it a shot, so i downloaded the ISO file, fired up Aomei partition assistant, after merging the ubuntu partition to the C: to get some space for windows 8.1 i went ahead and restarted the computer, AOMEI did its thing and it restarts again and comes up a black screen saying: "error: unknow filesystem. grub rescure>_ (the underscore is blinking) Please HELP!!! Note: I don't have the windows xp sp3 disc, because this is a used laptop

Answer (score 0):

MBR is broken ? - sounds not so good. Simply burn a live-CD with an *.iso-image of supergrub - supergrub can repair almost anything what looks like a broken grub.

supergrub can be obtained here (on the right side - "supergrub2" ) :

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Comment: can you provide me a link to supergrub where i can download it from?

Comment: Thanks! but now that i downloaded it, it comes up as an .img file i want to burn it to a USB what program can i use?

Comment: You downloaded it here ? : http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/

Comment: @DVORAK You downloaded it here ? : http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/     But it is here an *.iso - file ? - nah, anyway - you could install with ubuntu package manager this program "unetbootin" - this is a tool for to create usb-sticks - but don't know if this works only with *.iso - files or too with *.img - files ?!